# Why did \a match some non alphabetic characters

Tags: regular-expression

As my understanding, in the regex of Vim, `\a` matches any of alphabetic character.

Now I'm trying to change the line

```
file_exts = [tex, log, aux,]
```

into

```
file_exts = [(tex), (log), (aux),]
```

I've tried to execute `:s/\a\+\(.\{-}\ze,\)\{1}/\(\0\)/g`. The idea is to get the zones, which contains only alphabetic characters and ends with a `,` but exclude the `,`. And replace it with itself surrounded by a pair of `()`.

However, this command gave me `(file_exts = [tex), (log), (aux),]`

Of course, the spaces and the `[` are not alphabetic characters. But I don't know why they are matched too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\a` is indeed only matching alphabetical characters. The problem in your case is the `.\{-}` (similar to `.*`) which is matching a sequence of *any* characters in between the last alphabetical character and the comma.

(I also don't understand why you're creating a group `\(...\)` which can be repeated once `\{1}`.)

You can simplify your regexp to:

```
:s/\a\+\ze,/(\0)/g
```

Which matches a sequence of characters, followed by a comma (the comma is not part of the match) and replaces it with the same text of the match surrounded by parens.